# How to use concat instead of append, without having any Future Warning

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `append`

```
DF= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
DF = DF.append({'Col1': "A",  'Col2'  : 'B'  ,'Col3':  'C'},ignore_index=True)
```

Which was working fine, Now I try to use `concat` instead :

```
DF= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
DF = pd.concat([DF],pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A'],'Col2':['B'],'Col3':['C']}))
```

But this does throw the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: why is `DF` in a list by itself in the concat?  Both things you want to concat should be inside the list

Comment: concat needs a list of the DF,, place the second dataframe within square bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.concat` takes a list of dataframes to concatenate as the first argument. You should put both the dataframes in the list:

```py
DF= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
DF = pd.concat([DF, pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A'],'Col2':['B'],'Col3':['C']})])
```